# Is there any examples of realtime element resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, responsive-design

I have a concept that is similar to [newsmap.jp](http://newsmap.jp) where elements are given a value based on a specific value and they resize based on on that value in a grid like container in realtime with out any page refreshing

Has anyone every seen something like that? If not do you have any pointers in the right direction for how I would begin building it. I'm good with PHP but not so much with jquery.

**UPDATE 1**: These are good but I am looking for a script that is constantly resizing the elements (based on an algorithm). Basically it's something that is responsive to the sizes of the continuously changing elements in around it rather than something that changes only when the browser window re-sizes. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here http://masonry.desandro.com/

But you can change the size of divs or any other elements, with jquery/javascript.

See example on jquery:

```
<div id='test'>Lorem ipsum sit amet</div>

<script>$('#test').attr('width','200px');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a "Masonry" Effect? Look here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

There are several such plugins for jQuery. You can find a lot in this page:

http://www.wtfdiary.com/2012/08/6-amazing-jquery-plugins-to-design.html

and this page:

http://bashooka.com/coding/jquery-plugins-for-creating-grid-layout/

My favorite ones are isotope:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

and BlocksIt:

http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/